# How to access a host ssh tunnel from within a docker container?

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, ssh-tunnel

I'm creating a ssh tunnel, which I'm trying to access from within a docker container.

**On the Client a ssh tunnel is created**

```sh
ssh -R 0.0.0.0:8088:localhost:8088 user@my-server.com -N
```

**On the host/server**

```sh
# The tunneled connection is returning the expected page
curl localhost:8088
# Another service running directly on the host/server (not in docker container) which also works fine
curl localhost:8081
```

**Within the docker container**

```sh
# Create the docker container
docker run -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway ubuntu bash

# The tunneled connection will fail
curl localhost:8088
# > curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.1 port 8088 after 0 ms: Connection refused

# While the other service if accessible perfectly fine
curl localhost:8081
```

How can I make the tunneled connection available to the docker container?